# How to fix ListView WinRT in this case?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have proplem when i switch from Single to Multiple selection in ListView it will move left and my text have lost some character like picture
[image]

[image]

How i can fix it ? I want to change to Multiple selection and non hide character ?

Comment: Can you post your xaml?